# workflow to create multiple items to list_B based on defined column information in list_A

Tags: workflow

I work with SharePoint 2010, only using SharePoint Designer.

I have 2 lists:

- List_A which contains a list item with a multiselect column of locations.
- List_B to which I what a workflow to create as many list items as there are locations in the List_A multiselect columns of locations of the current list item.

The max number of locations is currently 8.

Example:

[image]

How do I define the workflow using only SP Designer?